# Serve static files from Cloudflare's R2

Tags: django, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

#### Architecture Description

I have a Django app hosted on an Azure App Service container and proxy through Cloudflare's DNS.

The app works great, and using [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/index.html) I am able to serve static files stored in the Azure App Service storage container that is provided with the App Service (10 GB). Thing is, the storage serves files used by the Web App only (files uploaded during build, there's no option to manually add other files), and it is limited to 100GB/month of egress bandwidth.

I would like to try and use [Cloudflare's R2](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/r2/) storage, as it has unlimited bandwidth, and allows you to upload any kind of files. I'll mainly be using images.

---

#### Question

How can static files be serve from Cloudflare's R2 on a Django app?

---

###### EDIT:

I have successfully connected to my Cloudflare's R2 bucket using [Boto3][1] but still can't link to the Django app on Azure.

Comment: Do you mean MEDIA files? Like uploaded by user via POST request into ImageField?

Comment: @IvanStarostin no, I mean Static files that are served to the clients from my server. My web app does not receive files from users.  Basically, it is to use R2 Storage as a CDN for my static files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well R2 will function as a CDN from a cost/latency perspective, but as long as you stay within the free limits it's probably mostly fine (TTFB latency is going to be the biggest issue as with any object store).

We are working on making it possible to put Cache in front of R2 so that will help on the performance & cost front once that becomes available.

Unfortunately, I think SO is going to be a poor medium to debug your issue as it's unclear. Perhaps get realtime help on the [R2 discord](https://discord.com/channels/595317990191398933/940663374377783388) and then come back here to post the answer once you figure out your issue?

Since this sounds like tricky work, if you have a working example, we're happy to host it on https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/examples/.